# Where am I throwing an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds 1 on a stack

Tags: java

I’m stumped. I am trying to write a program to get the tags of my dad's music. I have been looking at this code for almost 2 days now and I can't figure out where it could be throwing an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds:1 exception.

It works small scale perfectly but when I run it on my father's machine, it throws the exception after 92,000 songs done, he has over 300,000 songs.

Here is the code I’m using:

Any help would be appreciated.

```
while(!stack.isEmpty())
            {
                String data = "";
                String s = stack.pop();

                if (s.endsWith(".mp3"))
                {
                    count++;    i++;
                    Song song = new Song(new File(s));
                    data = song.toString();
                        DisplayGUI.setLoadingCurrent("CURRENTLY WORKING ON : " + Integer.toString(count) + 
                                                     " OF " + Integer.toString(total));
                        DisplayGUI.setLoadingData(new File(s).getPath());
                    writer.write(data + "\r\n");

                    if (i == 1000)                   // counter
                    {
                        System.out.println(count);
                        i = 0;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for (String ext : exts)
                    {
                        if (s.endsWith(ext))
                        {
                            count++;    i++;

                            data = data + "\"\",";                                                         // Empty Title
                            data = data + "\"\",";                                                         // Empty Artist
                            data = data + "\"\",";                                                         // Empty Album
                            data = data + "\"\",";                                                         // Empty Album Artist
                            data = data + "\"\",";                                                         // Empty Grouping
                            data = data + "\"\",";                                                         // Empty Genre
                            data = data + Long.toString(new File(s).length()) + ',';                       // Size
                            data = data + ',';                                                             // Empty Length
                            data = data + ',';                                                             // Empty Get Disc Number
                            data = data + ',';                                                             // Empty Get Total Disc Numbers
                            data = data + ',';                                                             // Empty Get Track Number
                            data = data + ',';                                                             // Empty Get Total Track Numbers
                            data = data + ',';                                                             // Empty Year
                            data = data + "\"" + ext + "\",";                                              // Ext
                            data = data + "\"\",";                                                         // Empty Comments
                            data = data + '\"' + new File(s).getPath() +'\"';                              // Path
                            data = data + ",\"" + new File(s).getParentFile().getAbsolutePath() + "\"";    // Folder
                            data = data + ",0";                                                            // Wins
                            data = data + ",0";                                                            // Loses
                            data = data + ",0";                                                            // Difference

                                DisplayGUI.setLoadingCurrent("CURRENTLY WORKING ON : " + Integer.toString(count) + 
                                                             " OF " + Integer.toString(total));
                                DisplayGUI.setLoadingData(new File(s).getPath());

                            writer.write(data + "\r\n");

                            if (i == 1000)                   // counter
                            {
                                System.out.println(count)
                                i = 0;
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: What is the error message? Does it tell you at what line of code it breaks?

Comment: You should provide more details; the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` will include a line number, which should say at which point your code is falling over at.

Comment: dear you also need to add exception stack trace. Include this whole code in a try catch block. SO when you execute and it fails you will get a stack trace. Post it here or use it to analyze the issue.

Comment: Are you using an IDE? Can you post the error message and step through the code to see where it's throwing it?

Comment: yeah executing the code in debug mode is good idea but. as he mentioned he is getting exception after 92K, it may be tough to debug

Comment: Depends on how consistent that 92k fail is ;)

Comment: true. he needs to work a little

Comment: Im running it in bluej and it crashes after running for over 12 hours. It has done it twice already. I have a try {} catch (Exception e) in place because of the writer, so that is the only message that I get.  It says ArrayIndexOutOfBounds: 1 and that is all I get

Comment: Where is the stack trace? It includes important information like the call hierarchy with line numbers. If you catch the exception you should print the stack trace with `e.printStackTrace()`. This will help to locate the error in the source code.

Comment: ok thank you, I will try that. I didn't know about that. I am still learning java. I hope that tells me all I need to know to fix it but if it doesn't then Ill post what it says